# In Vue, is it possible to route back to a component with a text area scrolled to the same place?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I'm using Vue.  When I'm on a page that has a textarea (full of lots of text) in it, and I route to a Settings page (for example), when I go back to the page with the textarea on it, I want it scrolled to the same place instead of to the top.  Is there some way I can make the VueRouter to not touch anything on the underlying component, even so that textareas and such are scrolled to the same place?

I am already using Keepalive, like this:

```html
<keep-alive>
  <router-view />
</keep-alive>
```

And on the Settings page, I go back like this:

```
$router.go(-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can record the scrollTop before entering the Settings page, then scroll to the corresponding position after going back to the page with the TextArea on it. Remember to clear the scrollTop record after you've done the scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by configuring Vue Router's [`scrollBehavior()`](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/scroll-behavior.html) to return `savedPosition`:

```js
// router.js
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'

Vue.use(VueRouter)

export default new VueRouter({
  routes: [
    //...
  ],
  scrollBehavior(to, from, savedPosition) {
    if (savedPosition) {
      return savedPosition;
    } else {
      return { x: 0, y: 0 };
    }
  }
})
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/return-to-scroll-position-on-back-button-jifr5?file=/src/router.js)